# Filtering an observable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I am sending a GET request from a service to an API, which returns a JSON array. I am having a hard time filtering the results. I was thinking of using rxjs find or filter, but I could not manage to do it.

Here's the original request:

```
TestRequest(): Observable<any> {
const nativeCall = this.nativeHttp.get('https:***' + this.formattedDate,
{ },
{'x-api-key': this.value, 'Content-Type':  'application/json'});
return from(nativeCall).pipe(
  map(Results => JSON.parse(Results.data))
);
```

}

And the format of the data from the API looks like this:

[image]

When I subscribe to the observable, I get all data from the JSON Array.
I need to filter only one specific item from [bc], which fulfills the requirements.
And I will later visualize it in template.

I would be extremely grateful for any advice.

Comment: 1. Share the json data 2. On what basis exactly do you want to filter the data?

Comment: Thank you very much @NicholasK Already made it work thanks to Yasser's reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` operator of RxJS helps to filter entire results of your observable stream.

In your case the best RxJS operator to use is a simple `map`, which can transform your result to a new shape of data.

Finally, to get one element from an array use can use the es6 array method `find`.

Example:

```js
const predicateFn = element => ...; // specify requirements.

return from(nativeCall).pipe(
  map(Results => JSON.parse(Results.data)),
  map(data => data.bc.find(e => predicateFn(e))) // create another map is optional
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Yasser! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
TestRequest(): Observable<any> {
const nativeCall = this.nativeHttp.get('https:***' + this.formattedDate,
{ },
{'x-api-key': this.value, 'Content-Type':  'application/json'});
return from(nativeCall).subscribe(result => {
 const filterdArr = result['data'].filter(element => yourCondition);
});
}
```